# Regex allow only one (possibly repeated) char from a given character class

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a string contains only one distinct char from a given character class. Some simple examples:

`"aa", "bbbbb", "c"` match this regex `[abc]+`, but the regex matches also `"abbb" or "abcbb"` which are not valid in my case. Therfore i can't use it.

Sample code:

```
String[] input = {"a", "aaa", "ab", "b", "bbbb", "abc", "ccc"};
for(String str :input){
    if(str.matches("[abc]+")){
        System.out.println(str + ": valid");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(str + ": not valid");
    }
}
```

The above will print valid for each string from the input array, which is not what I want. Valid inputs are only strings with distinct chars. I can achieve it with the following way , where i need to use multiple `or` in the if statement.

```
for(String str :input){
    if(str.matches("[a]+")||str.matches("[b]+")||str.matches("[c]+")){
        System.out.println(str + ": valid");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println(str + ": not valid");
    }
}
```

How can I achieve the same result as second aproach but write it compactly, because this will not be readable when the character class grows and there are changes in the character class I need to change the if condition?

Expected:

```
a: valid
aaa: valid
ab: not valid
b: valid
bbbb: valid
abc: not valid
ccc: valid
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\1` (escaped as `\\1`) to reference the first subgroup's match, so something like:

```
^([a-z])\1+$
```

.. would match a-z followed by itself at least once as the only characters in the string (the ^ and $ might be implicit with `.matches`, I'm not too familiar with Java specific issues with regexes).

You then need one additional check to see if the string has the length of 1 and contains `a-z` (if you want to avoid allowing 1, 2, etc. and other special characters).

Comment: You probably need `^([abc])\1*$` as OP wants to allow single character also.

Comment: Thank you very much. Exactly what i need.

Answer (score 2):

See "Repeating Character Classes" in https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

TL;DR; `^([a-z])\1*$`

Note: Thar be dragons, depending on quoting strength you may need to double escape the backslash: `^([a-z])\\1*$`

Comment: Thank you for the link. Very helpfull.